# How to force a MySQL query to return a 0 when the result of query is nothing?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
SUM(quantity) AS qt
FROM 
stockMove
WHERE
date_mov >= '2019-04-01'
AND
date_mov <= '2019-04-30'
AND
ProductCode = '000807'
GROUP BY 
ProductCode
```

If a have no movement of this product in this date range, the query returns nothing, but I need that to return 0.

I already try:

> SELECT SUM(quantity) AS qt, COALESCE(quantity, 0)

and

> SELECT SUM(quantity) AS qt, IFNULL(quantity, 0)

but the query still returns 0 rows.

Is there a way to resolve my issue?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, just remove the `GROUP BY` and use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS qt
FROM stockMove
WHERE date_mov >= '2019-04-01' AND date_mov <= '2019-04-30' AND
      ProductCode = '000807';
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns one row, even when no rows match.  The returned value is `NULL` -- which is where the `COALESCE()` comes in.

With the `GROUP BY`, the query returns no rows at all.  Can't convert nothing into a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below-

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS qt
```

Comment: . . The OP includes (essentially) this logic in the question and explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain **why** one should use that? Keep in mind that such an explanation helps others to understand your code